# how can I center child div inside parent div with margins?

Tags: css, wordpress

Here is the code

```
div.content_inner {
    background-color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

Website is http://twoandahalfmiles.polymath.io

I'm trying to get the white content are to have margins on each side and I want it to stretch to the top of the website, it doesn't currently do that either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a fixed width, and set the left and right side margin value of auto.Like this:

```
.content {
  width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: atuo;
}
div.content_inner {
    background-color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 10px #000;
   /* margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;*/　/*please delete*/
}
```

Comment: That worked fantastically.. Any chance you have some advice for making it full height? It's also now over my logo so it is not clickable anymore. And if I want, can I make my slider full width?

Comment: Ya know.. doing it that fixed way also loses my responsiveness.. any ideas?

Comment: you can use the background-position.